# How to update the text in a listView with the DownloadFileAsync progress percentage?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently making a podcast client to download episodes. I have got a listView filled with the episodes for a feed and then when you double click on one it places it into a separate 'downloads' lisview which has a 'name' and a 'progress' column.

The problem I am having is trying to individually update each progress while downloading asynchronously. As I am not sure of how to keep track of the progress for each ListViewItem and how to reference it in the downloadProgressChanged function.

```
        private void lvPodDownloads_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lvPodEpisodes.SelectedItems.Count == 1) // Check if an item is selected just to be safe
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)lvPodEpisodes.SelectedItem;
            string[] epInfo = (string[])item.Tag;
            txtTitle.Text = epInfo[0];
            txtDesc.Text = epInfo[1];

            try
            {
                imgFeedImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri((Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\..\\..\\feedImages\\" + epInfo[3])));
            }
            catch (Exception) // If it fails to set the image (Eg. It's non-existent) It will leave it blank
            {
                imgFeedImage.Source = null;
            }
        }
    }
    private void lvPodEpisodes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) // Downloading the episode in here
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) // Left button was double clicked
        {
            ListViewItem selected = (ListViewItem)lvPodEpisodes.SelectedItem;
            string[] epInfo = (string[])selected.Tag;

            Uri downloadUrl = new Uri(epInfo[2]);



            List<Episode> downloading = new List<Episode>();
            downloading.Add(new Episode() { Title = epInfo[0], Progress = "0%" });
            lvPodDownloads.Items.Add((new Episode() { Title = epInfo[0], Progress = "0%" }));
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    static int intDownloadProgress = new int();
    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        intDownloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download completed!");
    }
```

This is a code sample of the downloading section of the program.

Here is an image of what I have so far:
https://s33.postimg.cc/gthzioxlr/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an extra argument to your ProgressChanged method.

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Episode curEpisode)
{
    curEpisode.Progress = $"{e.ProgressPercentage} %";
}
```

And to modify the handler setting like that:

```
List<Episode> downloading = new List<Episode>();
var newEpisode = new Episode() { Title = epInfo[0], Progress = "0%" };  

downloading.Add(newEpisode);
lvPodDownloads.Items.Add(newEpisode);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, newEpisode));
}
```

The static property *intDownloadProgress* is then useless.

You should also think about using an observable collection for the episode list and using  it for the binding via the XAML code.

Comment: Thanks for the help I will give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: I ended up looking into the observable collections you mentions and that proved far more helpful I managed to get it working great. Thanks a lot.